How to dynamically change filter for a joined report?
I have a joined report where I need to pass account Id for the filter on the 2 blocks I have in the report. I am able to do this for a normal report but not sure if we have a way to do this for a joined report. Below formula works for a normal report and by keeping the account id in the filter empty:
/lightning/r/Report/00OSu000000mmIGU3Y/view?fv0={!Account.Id}


https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYVGUA3/passing-url-parameters-to-joined-reports
